# An example of open set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ for which $C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{l,p}(\Omega)$

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

We know that the statement *$C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R^n})$ is dense in $W^{l,p}(\mathbb{R^n})$* is always true for any $l\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p\geq \infty$, $p\neq \infty$. My professor told me that it also holds for special open sets $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$, but I cannot find an example of such $\Omega$.

Do anyone know something about this? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you did not mean to write $p\ge\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for domains $\Omega$ for which $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) = W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. This will be the case if $\partial \Omega$ has $p$-capacity equal to $0$. Look e.g. in *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* by Evans and Gariepy, or *Function Spaces and Potential Theory* by Adams and Hedberg.